# SelectPicker adding options dynamically depend input value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-selectpicker

Morning,
I'm trying to create a table with dropdown (selectpicker A) fill dynamically with data selected with result of other input (selectpicker B) not into this table.
Filling (SelectPicker A) its OK for first row of table after selected value into SelectPicker B.
But when i add new line (by clone), SelectPicker A is empty for second row.
Need your help, thks !

My view code :

```
 <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="nc_A" id="nc_A" onchange="select_B(this)" type="string" required>
      <option disabled> </option>
</select>
...
<table id="sub_table" class="table">
    <thead">
        <tr>                               
            <th>{{__('test.B')}}</th>                                  
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" name="nc_B[]" id="nc_B" type="string" required>
                    <option> </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

 <i class="btn" onclick="add_row()">{{" + ".__('home.ajoutligne')}}</i>
```

My Jquery code :

```
var clonednc = $("#sub_table tbody tr:first").clone()
 $("select[name*=nc_B]").selectpicker()
 
function add_row() {
    $(clonednc).find("input").val("")
    
    $("<tr>" + $(clonednc).html() + "</tr>").appendTo($("#sub_table tbody"))
    $("#sub_table tbody tr:last select").selectpicker()
}

function select_B(e)
{
    var selectionA = e.value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/production/selectionB",
        data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, ncA : selectionA },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
            $(e).parents('div').find('#nc_B').empty();

            $.each(data, function(key,value){
                $(e).parents('div').find('#nc_B').append('<option value="'+value.NumB+'">'+ value.NumB +'</option>');
            });

            $("select[name*=nc_B]").selectpicker('refresh');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Morning, Someone can help me ?

Comment: Resend.........